# PHP output buffer is not empty?

Tags: php

I have this peculiar problem. I am making an AJAX call to a PHP page. In case of error I am returning the string "error" to success: `function(msg)` i.e. msg will have the value "error". But for some reason it is sending back "error" but with a line break preceding it. And this fails the condition when i check `if (msg=="error")`. I have to put `ob_clean()` to clear out the output buffer. Then it returns "error" without line break. I checked but my PHP function is not outputting anything before the "error". What can be the issue that the output buffer is not empty?

Comment: why not show your code as an example? Could be a simple output before you expect your condition response.

Comment: Along with the answer below, perhaps you should consider sending back JSON from your PHP? jQuery supports it (of course), and PHP will let you send anything as JSON using [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2):

That happens because some of your php files has an empty line before `<?php` or after `?>`

As PhpMyCoder propsed - you could also not put `?>` in the end of the file at all. Php allows doing that.

Comment: You might want to include that it might be helpful to not place end tags at the end of a php file so postfixed extraneous characters are ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your views. I am going to browse my code and see what could be the problem.

Comment: @Blueboye Additionally, if the file is saved as UTF8 with BOM, PHP will output few bytes (the BOM) before the actual output

Comment: @Darhazer: known BOMs take 2-4 bytes, not just 1